# datatool & etoolbox - more expansion shenanigans

Tags: etoolbox, datatool

This is the code in question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fp}

\def\initialValue{10}
\DTLnewdb{thisEntryDBWarehouse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifstartswith}[2]{%
\if\@car#1.\@nil\@car#2.\@nil
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\evalModifier}[1]{
  \ifstartswith{#1}{+}{\FPeval\result{clip(#1+\initialValue)}\result}{
    \ifstartswith{#1}{-}{\FPeval\result{clip(#1+\initialValue)}\result}{
      #1
    }
  }
}

\newcommand{\addEntry}[3]{%
  \def\thisValue{\evalModifier{#2}}
  \thisValue
  % \def\thisValue{#2}

  \ifcsname thisEntry#1\thisValue\endcsname
    \cseappto{thisEntry#1\thisValue}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\\}} & #3 }%
  \else
    \DTLnewrow{thisEntryDB#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{thisEntryDB#1}{value}{\thisValue}%
    \csedef{thisEntry#1\thisValue}{{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\bf \thisValue} & #3}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\printAllEntries}[1]{%
%   % Packs all the events in thisCharEvents tmp var
  \edef\thisList{}
  \DTLsort{value}{thisEntryDB#1}
  \DTLforeach*{thisEntryDB#1}{\theValue=value}{\edef\thisList{\expandonce{\thisList} \csuse{thisEntry#1\theValue} \unexpanded{\\}}%
  }
  % Prints them in a table - if they exist
  \ifdefempty{\thisList}{}{\paragraph{\bf Entries:}\mbox{}%
  \begin{longtable}{c p{9cm}}%
    Value & Description\\
    \thisList%
  \end{longtable}%
  }
}


\begin{document}

 \addEntry{Warehouse}{10}{Entry 0}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{10}{Entry 1}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{12}{Entry 2}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{+0}{Entry 3}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{+2}{Entry 4}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{11}{Entry 5}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{+3}{Entry 6}
 \addEntry{Warehouse}{-2}{Entry 7}

 \printAllEntries{Warehouse}
\end{document}
```

Expected output was the following table:

```
 8 Entry 7
10 Entry 0
   Entry 1
   Entry 3
11 Entry 5
12 Entry 2
   Entry 4
13 Entry 6
```

but the source fails to compile. Line 29 is there only to test if \evalModifier is doing its job correctly (it seems to be). Line 30 is there because the rest of the \addEntry macro doesn't seem to cope well with the value of \thisValue. And this is one of the problems. I've tried using edef on line 28 instead of def, but then \evalModifier doesn't work.

There is another problem. If you uncomment line 30, it will compile, except that line 36 seems to be expanding \thisValue only too late. All entries end up with "-2" at their value column.

Comment: You need to switch on expansion if you use constructs like `\DTLnewdbentry{...}{...}{\thisValue}` with `\dtlexpandnewvalue`. Expansion is off by default.